# Secret Key environment variable not working on Ubuntu. Django, Postgres, Gunicorn, Nginx, Virtualenv

Tags: django, postgresql, nginx, environment-variables, gunicorn

This is the following error I get when I try to run the makemigrations command while my virtualenv is active:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "manage.py", line 22, in <module>
    execute_from_command_line(sys.argv)
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 363, in execute_from_command_line
    utility.execute()
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/core/management/__init__.py", line 307, in execute
    settings.INSTALLED_APPS
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 56, in __getattr__
    self._setup(name)
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 41, in _setup
    self._wrapped = Settings(settings_module)
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/site-packages/django/conf/__init__.py", line 110, in __init__
    mod = importlib.import_module(self.SETTINGS_MODULE)
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/importlib/__init__.py", line 126, in import_module
    return _bootstrap._gcd_import(name[level:], package, level)
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 986, in _gcd_import
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 969, in _find_and_load
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 958, in _find_and_load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 673, in _load_unlocked
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap_external>", line 665, in exec_module
  File "<frozen importlib._bootstrap>", line 222, in _call_with_frames_removed
  File "/home/tony/vp/vp/config/settings/production.py", line 1, in <module>
    from .base import *
  File "/home/tony/vp/vp/config/settings/base.py", line 22, in <module>
    SECRET_KEY = os.environ["VP_SECRET_KEY"]
  File "/home/tony/vp/vpenv/lib/python3.5/os.py", line 725, in __getitem__
    raise KeyError(key) from None
KeyError: 'VP_SECRET_KEY'
```

I have set my environment variables inside three locations:

in my **virtual environments bin/activate script**:

```
Environment=VP_SECRET_KEY="****"

Environment=VP_DB_PASS="****"
```

in the **.bashrc** file:

```
VP_SECRET_KEY="****"

VP_DB_PASS="****"
```

and in my **gunicorn.service** file:

```
[Unit]
Description=gunicorn daemon
After=network.target

[Service]
User=tony
Environment=VP_SECRET_KEY="****"
Environment=VP_DB_PASS="****"
Group=www-data
WorkingDirectory=/home/tony/vp/vp/
ExecStart=/home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application


[Install]
WantedBy=multi-user.target
```

Here is how I import it in my **settings base.py** (i use multiple settings files):

```
# SECURITY WARNING: keep the secret key used in production secret!
SECRET_KEY = os.environ["VP_SECRET_KEY"]
```

when I echo them by using $VP_SECRET_KEY I do get the value returned.

What can cause this problem? could it be that by setting them in multiple locations there is some sort of collission?

Comment: why not simple add `SECRET_KEY = ` to the `local_settings.py ` and import it in the `settings.py` ? of course you need add `local_settings.py ` to `.gitignore`

Comment: I have all my settings files (base.py, production.py, local.py) version controlled. I don't want my secret key to be visible in any of them for security reasons. If that's what you mean :P

Comment: ok, create new for example `secret.py` add it to the `.gitignore`, why not?

Comment: Thanks @BearBrown, but what I tried to do was answered by Tarun Lalwani in his answer! Thank you though!

Comment: not at all, as you prefer )

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is you are viewing a SESSION variable

```
$ MYNAME=TARUN
$ env
```

output of env won't show MYNAME because it is a variable in current BASH. So you need to export it

```
export VP_SECRET_KEY="****"    
export VP_DB_PASS="****"
```

**Edit 1**

Also if you want you can pass environment variable through gunicorn

```
ExecStart=/home/tony/vp/vpenv/bin/gunicorn -e VP_SECRET_KEY=***** --workers 3 --bind unix:/home/tony/vp/vp/vp.sock vp.wsgi:application
```

Comment: whaaaaat, I am a fool! Thank you, Tarun! can't believe I forgot to export them

Comment: @TonyKyriakidis, no worries happens. That's why its always good have someone take a look